# Apple Music "My library"/"Apple Music" slider toggle button in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button, android-styles

I'm trying to achieve a Apple Music like slider button:

[image]

I have the style for the button that is checked and for the one that is unchecked:

```
 <style name="Theme.My.Buttons.Outlined" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">11dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.My.Buttons.Active" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">11dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small</item>
    </style>
```

This is my xml file with the buttons, currently I used the styles manually:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".fragments.SearchFragment">
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/Theme.My.Buttons.Outlined"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/Theme.My.Buttons.Active"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            />

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I set the checked style when the button is checked and unchecked style when it is unchecked? Also, is it possible for me to do a slide like animation?

I tried using a drawable file setting the style to when it is checked and when it is unchecked, but in the field style I can't put a drawable resource file

Comment: You have to use a color state list instead of fixed colors.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Can you please give me more details? Also, is it possible to change the style, not the only the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it!

You have to create a xml file with the color for when the button is checked or not. I used here 4 files for the background, because I wanted to have the outside corners rounded but the inside not, so I had to create 2 backgrounds for each side, one for when it is checked and one to when it isn't checked.
If I used the same background file there would be a problem with the single side rounded corner as on the left side the outside corner is the left and on the right side it is the right

These are thef files:

These to define the backgrounds from when it is checked and when it isn't:
Selected right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners
       android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
       android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/slider_button_corner_size"
       android:topRightRadius="@dimen/slider_button_corner_size"
       />

   <solid android:color="@color/android_darker_gray" />

</shape>
```

regular right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners

       android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
       android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/slider_button_corner_size"
       android:topRightRadius="@dimen/slider_button_corner_size"
       />
   <solid android:color="@color/white" />

   <stroke
       android:width="0.5dp"
       android:color="@color/slider_button_outline_color_unchecked" />
</shape>
```

regular left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
       <corners

           android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/slider_button_corner_size"
           android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/slider_button_corner_size"
           android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
           android:topRightRadius="0dp"
           />
       <solid android:color="@color/white" />

       <stroke
           android:width="0.5dp"
           android:color="@color/slider_button_outline_color_unchecked" />
   </shape>
```

selected left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners
       android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/slider_button_corner_size"
       android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/slider_button_corner_size"
       android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
       android:topRightRadius="0dp"
       />
   <solid android:color="@color/android_darker_gray" />

</shape>
```

These to define what background will be used when it is checked and when it isnt:

Definer Right:

definer left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_background_selected_left" android:state_checked="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_background_regular_left" />
</selector>
```

Then on the layout where you want to use it put:

```
<RadioGroup
   android:id="@+id/radioGroupSliderSearch"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
   android:checkedButton="@id/radioButtonMyMaterialsSearch"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


   <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/radioButtonMyMaterialsSearch"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background_definer_left"
       android:button="@android:color/transparent"
       android:checked="true"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Meus Materiais"
       android:textColor="@color/radio_button_text_definer"
       android:textSize="10sp" />

   <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/radioButtonEdugatherSearch"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background_definer_right"
       android:button="@android:color/transparent"
       android:checked="false"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="EduGather"
       android:textColor="@color/radio_button_text_definer"
       android:textSize="10sp" />

</RadioGroup>
```

And that's it!